# Prevent functions from showing up in source - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a general question.

Normally any code we write in Angular is compiled into a bundle file which is served to the browser right?! This JavaScript code which we write is visible as it is in the bundle file while viewing source. How do we prevent our code from being propagated. Is there any Obfuscator that works in real time for protecting our algorithms?

Answer (score 3):

Try plugins to suit your needs. Modern angular versions come with webpack which can do minification and mangling. There are limitations to JavaScript obfuscation especially for angular code which needs certain keywords to work that cannot be changed. If you need to hide code consider moving it to server. All JavaScript client code should be considered vulnerable to being read.